# How can I terminate a background process with ctrlz in C?

Tags: c, linux, signals, background-process

I'm writing a script in C and I execute it with the `&` in order to run it on the background.
I need to terminate the program with ctrl-z (SIGTSTP)

There is a main loop that intentionally prevents the script from terminating.
I need to terminate it with ctrl-z and ctrl-z will not respond while the process is running the background.

How can I send the signal(from terminal) to the background process and how can I manipulate it?

Comment: Have you tried CTRL+D?

Comment: Did you mean `Ctrl-C`? The `Ctrl-Z` (Windows) or `Ctrl-D` (Linux) does not terminate a process: they close the `stdin` stream.

Comment: I can terminate it with ctrl-c but im told to terminate it with ctrl-z (SIGTSTP signal). So i need to handle the signal and then terminate the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to handle the signal and terminate the program when you receive the signal SIGTSTP.

To understand what I'm talking about: [C signal handling - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling)

Any guide/manual about handling signals in C should help you.

P.S.: you can terminate the program in any moment with function [`exit()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit) from `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: I understand your point, the thing is that SIGTSTP will not be sent to the background process(and that is what Im trying to figure out now) so that I can handle the signal

Comment: In order to send the signal to a process using the command line, you can use `kill -20 PID`, where `PID` is the pid of your script (P.S.: `-20` means `SIGTSTP`). In order to know the pid of your program, you can simply print it (or write it to file) when your program starts. Use function [`getpid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) in order to obtain the current pid of your program.